# Desenvolvimento de uma aplicação com webservice como abordar

Tags: laravel, web-service, ionic

Estou realizando um projeto que consiste em uma plataforma online para gerenciamento de uma clinica, onde deve conter um site e um aplicativo.

A minha ideia principal é criar um WebService para atender as requisições tanto da plataforma quanto do aplicativo.

Meu projeto seria em Laravel e Ionic.

1 Solução:
Criar a plataforma com Laravel e fazer meu aplicativo acessar essa mesma plataforma para acessar os dados

2 Solução:
Criar a plaforma em Laravel, e meu webService também em Laravel. assim o Aplicativo acessa somente o webservice.

Teria algum problema em criar a minha plataforma e meu webservice ambos em lavel? eu teria uma perca de desempenho ou alguma outra desvantagem?